# How to make ConfigurationManager read a config file other than app.config?

Tags: .net, app-config, configurationmanager

I need to parse a config file that is situated in another project. I know that ConfigurationManager reads the app.config file by default, but how to make it read that particular config file?

Comment: By default the app reads the config file from the project that has the entry point to the app. If you instead want to read from a config file within the project use the [ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration][0] method. Here is an [example][1] that uses this method. [0]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134269.aspx
[1]:http://dotnetanalysis.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-read-from-config-file-within.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
// Create a filemap refering the config file.
ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = configFilePath;

// Retrieve the config file.
Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or like this:

```
var fileMap = new ConfigurationFileMap(configFilePath);
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(fileMap);
```

But you still will have a problem with custom configuration sections.