# Reading Another Application's Web.Config to get ConnectionString

Tags: c#, winforms, web-config

How can I read another application to get connectionString ..
I have path of web.config File
But there are multiple connection strings in it and I want to get the only non commented connection string.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DbConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\abcd\Data\abcd.accdb;" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>
  <!--<add name="DbConString" connectionString="Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=123;Initial Catalog=abc;Data Source=afrt-WIN7JPN-80\SQLEXPRESS" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>-->
</connectionStrings>
```

How can I get the non commented `DbConString`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using configurationmanager to read from multiple web.config files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062045/using-configurationmanager-to-read-from-multiple-web-config-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done by simply reading Web.Config with `XmlDocument`

```
 string connStr = "";
 XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
 xdoc.Load(WebConfigPath);
 XmlNode xnodes = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/connectionStrings");

  foreach (XmlNode xnn in xnodes.ChildNodes)
  {
     if (xnn.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Comment)
     { 
     }
     else
     {
       connStr = xnn.Attributes["connectionString"].Value.ToString();
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
var filePath = @"D:\PathToConfig\Web.config";
var map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = filePath };
var configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

As shown 
[here!](http://blog.thekfactor.info/posts/programatically-accessing-a-web-config/)

Comment: This code was what I was looking for, and with this line I was able to get the connection strings as data objects like normal:   `var section = (ConnectionStringsSection)configFile.GetSection("connectionStrings");`