# WCF Service web.config not being retrieved via WebConfigurationManager

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config

I'm currently running a WCF service on localhost, with a web.config file that contains credentials to connect to CRM. The web.config file, which is in the root of the project, contains the appSettings as you'd expect:

```
  <appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
<add key="CrmUrl" value="{removed}"/>
<add key="CrmUser" value="{removed}"/>
<add key="CrmPass" value="{removed}"/>
  </appSettings>
```

I then try to retrieve these values with an initialiser

```
internal CrmOrganizationServiceContext Crm
        {
            get
            {
                return CrmConnectionCreator.CreateConnection(
                    WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CrmUrl"], 
                    WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CrmUser"], 
                    WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CrmPass"]);
            }            
        }
```

However, `null` is being passed through to the `CreateConnection` method. I did a little digging around google, and most suggestions are regarding using `WebConfigurationManager`, which I currently am doing. Calling `WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null)` seems to pass me to a web.config file which exists in the Microsoft.NET framework installation folder, when I'm trying to read in configuration settings from the web.config file in my project.

Is `WebConfigurationManager` looking in the wrong area, and I have to point it to the right location somehow? I have also tried using plain `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` but the results are the same.

Comment: I use ConfigurationManager.AppSettings in some services and woks fine. Is the Web.config file in the service folder, above of bin folder level?

Comment: @RicardoPontual The web.config file is in the root of the project, whereas the service is in a separate folder "~root/Client/MyService.svc"

Comment: That must the issue. Maybe ExeConfigurationFileMap can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062045/using-configurationmanager-to-read-from-multiple-web-config-files